# How to debug C++ code in Visual studio code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, c++14

Anyone using Visual studio code for programming in C++? Please tell me how can i manage to do the debugging of my code in visual studio code when I'm compiling it using g++ compiler.

Comment: do you mean "launch.json"?

Comment: ohh yes, launch.json my bad.

Comment: Are you using Cygwin, MinGW, or WSL?

If you are using WSL, you can find more information here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/Debugger/gdb/Windows%20Subsystem%20for%20Linux.md

In your tasks.json, make sure to compile with the -g flag for symbols.

Comment: using minGW. Can you show me the syntax of that, to add -g before compiling.

Answer (score 2):

For debugging multiple cpp files inside the project directory.

Your launch.json and task.json should look like this

```
tasks.json



{
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }

launch.json

{
        "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
          {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
          }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
    }
```